# How to delete a volume in docker if it is being used by containers

Tags: linux, docker

I have a task in which they have sent us to delete a docker volume which has a container associated with it, I would like to know if there is any way to delete the volume without deleting the container that is using it.

I have tried the following but it won't let me:

```
sudo docker volume rm -f vol1
```

It returns the following.

```
Error response from daemon: remove vol1: volume is in use - [a90d72c647bf7cdf2a3d8d8f0005163f072e4f6da80f27bca7b81f437f2f21d3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the volume, you will have to remove/stop the container first. Deleting volumes will wipe out their data. Back up any data that you need before deleting a container.

```
Stop/Remove the container(s)
Delete the volume(s)
Restart the container(s) (if you did stop)
```

Answer (score 3):

To delete all containers including its volumes used

```
sudo docker rm -vf $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way, although for this I have to stop the container that uses it and delete it. I leave it here in case anyone is interested, although I would like to know if there is any way to eliminate the volume without touching the container

```
sudo docker stop <container>
sudo docker rm <container>
sudo docker volume rm <volume>
```

Answer (score 1):

if it was created by compose, see this question see also [Docker is in volume in use, but there aren't any Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658836/docker-is-in-volume-in-use-but-there-arent-any-docker-containers)

and this :
[Docker is in volume in use, but there aren't any Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658836/docker-is-in-volume-in-use-but-there-arent-any-docker-containers#comment69028914_34658836)

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```